# sumif not adding up correctly

Tags: sumifs

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet here]

My SUMIF formula in B20 is returning a total value of $7.00 but it should be $13.00 because I am trying to add up the values in B14, B15, B16 and B17. It only seems to be capturing the value in B14. B13 is a drop down with two options, New Form and Old Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work like that.

In first argument you need to provide range of cells to provide value for criteria in second argument to check if value in cell from range in third argument had to be added to sum.

So, given data:

```
A       B
---------
a       7
a       2
a       2
```

and formula in cell B4:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A3;"a";B1:B3)
```

you'll get `11` in result.

given data:

```
A       B
---------
a       7
b       2
a       2
```

you'll get `9` in result.

Comment: Thank you! I see how it works now. How would I set up a formula to add up B14:B17 based only on the condition that cell B13 is "New Form"?

Comment: You can't. Range from first argument must match with third (in length).

Comment: I see, I tried =IF(B13="New Form", SUM(B14:B17), SUM(B15:B16,B19) and this worked. Thank you for your help!